AdminJS with @adminjs/relations on NestJS rendering error: Error: Component "RelationsShowPropertyComponent" has not been bundled
I wrote a implementation of relations (one to many and many to many) using the @adminjs/relations but is generating the following error in the visual generated resources that have this relations:
Admin page error
This is the browser console output:
Console error 1
Console error 2
And this is my resources:
const createStreamingResource = () => ({
    resource: Streaming,
    options: {
        navigation: {
            icon: 'Users'
        },
    },
    features: [owningRelationSettingsFeature({
        componentLoader,
        licenseKey: process.env.LICENSE_KEY,
        relations: {
            members: {
                type: RelationType.ManyToMany,
                junction: {
                    joinKey: 'streamingId',
                    inverseJoinKey: 'collaboratorId',
                    throughResourceId: 'StreamingCollaborator',
                },
                target: {
                    resourceId: 'Collaborator',
                },
            },
        },
    }), ],
});

And my packege.json:
package.json
I need to solve this problem and make my program have the same appearance as the official documentation, which can be found at this link AdminJS Relations
